# Loop through selected local storage items through FOR- loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, local-storage

I have been experimenting with JavaScript, and seem to be dealing what I think is a really dumb lost-in-syntax problem. I have created a simple code that compares data from a Json files with the ones stored in the local storage for matching values:

What I have been unable to do, is getting the code more "elegant" and instead of those ugly (preset) || operands insert another FOR-loop that loops through the local storage data.

What I have been trying is:

```
var aerei = vristoranti[idris].menu.length;

for (i=0; i<aerei; i++){
    var aeromobile = vplanes[counter].book[i].name;
    for (j=1; j<4; j++){
        if (aeromobile == vplanes[0].d+i){
            cont1 ++; 
        } 
    }
    cont2+=cont1;
}
```

I tried / "d"+i / 'd'+i / 'd+1' / store the int for the converting it into string and concat...etc, etc, but nothing seems to be working. Doing vplanes[0].randomvariable doesn't work either, cause the parser tries to find the var "randomvariable" in the local storage, instead of the value of that variable (looped as d1, d2, d3).

Can someone tell me what am I missing?? I thank you all in advance and wish you a great we.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
vplanes[0]['d' + i]
```

Comment: Works like a charme! Thank you pal!